# How can the app tell which folder the user selected in the Database Folder dialog?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dialog, desktop-application, installshield-2012

Using Installshield 2012 Spring to build a setup.exe for a C#.Net  Windows app, how can the app tell which folder the user selected in the Database Folder dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Set InstallShield to have MSI write a log.
Have the app look for a line like the following in the log

PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying DATABASEDIR property. Its current value is 'C:\Database\'. Its new value: 'C:\'.

Details: InstallShield/Installation Designer/General/Create MSI Logs/Yes.
To find the log file Use Run/%temp%
Write code in the app to read this log file, search for the key lines and thus get the answer.